# Refinement of a theorem of Koblitz-Ogus

Tags: nt.number-theory, periods

In their appendix to Deligne's paper "Valeurs de fonctions L et périodes d'intégrales" (PSPM 33, 1979), Koblitz and Ogus prove that functions $N^{-1}\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{Z}-\{0\}\to \mathbf{Q}$ verifying certain relations are spanned by very specific ones; in the remark at the end of this appendix (p. 345 of the article), they say that Kubert has obtained an integral refinement of this result. I looked for it in Kubert's papers but could not find it there: maybe it is put in a different formulation. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Probably
D. Kubert, The universal ordinary distribution, Bull. Soc. Math. Fr 107 (1979), 179-202.

Comment: Thank you; I had consulted it. Can you point out where?